# Is it possible to get owncloud running from a home network?

Tags: networking, sync, home-networking, owncloud

I don't want to maintain a server, or keep my computer running 24/7. I just want to to have control over my files, and be able to sync between all my devices when I am home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NAS as a server. The ones from [Synology](http://www.synology.com/us/), even [this old one](http://www.synology.com/us/products/DS109j/), are able to run [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/). [image: Synology 109j NAS]

[Here is how to install ownCloud on a Synology DiskStation.](http://www.eg-blog.de/?page_id=399) I have done that, and although this old NAS is a bit slow, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

However, the server will need to be running for you to access/sync your files - so you will need it running any time you want to look through/sync/etc.  Ideally, you could get a low powered server (an old laptop, a raspberry pi, etc.) that is cheap to power and you can simply leave it running all the time.

Comment: Would you possibly now of any tutorials of how to set one up on a mac running snow Leopard?

Comment: @Hebon - [this](http://doc.owncloud.org/server/5.0/admin_manual/installation.html#mac-os-x) is pretty straight forward I think.  Not ideal since you need MAMP as well, but it'll work.